# $2$-norm of idempotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose $n > 1$ is an integer. Let $P \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ be a matrix such that $P^2=P$ and $1\leqslant {\rm rank}(P)<n$. Prove that $\Vert P \Vert_2 = \Vert I - P \Vert_2$.

I have been working on the problem for hours. Please let me know if any can help. Thanks!

Comment: See here: https://www.math.nthu.edu.tw/~amen/2014/131012(final).pdf

Comment: What makes you think the equation does hold?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed. This is nontrivial, see the nice reference given by Christian Remling.

Comment: @abx: I beg to disagree: the proof in that reference is ingenious, but entirely elementary. Furthermore, things are easier in this post because the Hilbert space is finite-dimensional, so in principle one has more ways of attacking the problem. This is definitely a good question for MSE, undoubtedly, but maybe less so for MO.

Comment: @Alex M.: Is there a simpler proof in the finite-dimensional case? Anyway, I agree that this is not a research question. But I have seen more elementary questions well-received on MO...

Comment: @abx: I have no idea if one can come up with an even simpler proof than the one in the reference. On the other hand, please notice that here the OP asks about the norm $\| \cdot \| _2$ (i.e. $P$ is viewed as an $n^2$-dimensional vector), whereas in the reference one works with the operator norm. Maybe that proof can be adapted to this situation, I haven't tried.

Comment: @Alex M.: I think the OP meant the operator norm w.r.t. ${\lVert\  \rVert}_2$ on $\Bbb{C}^n$ — otherwise this is trivially false.

Comment: Also @AlexM. I agree with abx (my first interpretation of the question was yours, but then once I realized there are diagonal counterexamples I assumed that -- as is sometimes commonplace in matrix analysis -- $\Vert \cdot\Vert_p$ is used for the $\ell_p^n\to \ell_p^n$ norm. (The Hilbert-Schmidt norm is then often denoted, in those sources, by "F" for "Frobenius.)

Answer (score 5):

This is very easy to confirm when $n=2$: We can then also assume that $Pe_1=e_1$, so
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} ,
$$
and $\|P\|=\| 1-P\| = \sqrt{1+|a|^2}$.

In general, pick an $x$ with $\|x\|=1, \|Px\| = \|P\|$ and restrict $P$ to the invariant subspace $V$ spanned by $x,Px$. Then $\dim V=2$ and $P\not= 0,1$ also on $V$, unless we are in the trivial case $\|P\|=1$, so the first part shows that $\|(1-P)\bigr|_V\|=\|P\|$. Thus $\|1-P\|\ge \|P\|$ and then also $\|1-P\|=\| P\|$ by symmetry.

(This argument, very slightly modified, also works in general, when $\dim H=\infty$.)

Answer (score 3):

Let $U$, $V$ be the image and kernel of $P$, respectively. Then $\mathbb{C}^n=U\oplus V$ and for fixed $C>1$ we have
$$
\|P\|\leqslant C\\\Leftrightarrow \forall u\in U, v\in V\colon\,\|u\|^2\leqslant C^2 \|u+v\|^2 \\
\Leftrightarrow \forall u\in U, v\in V\colon\,0\leqslant (C^2-1) \|u\|^2+2C^2 \Re \langle u,v\rangle+C^2 \|v^2\|\\
\Leftrightarrow\forall u\in U, v\in V,t\in \mathbb{R}\colon 0\leqslant
(C^2-1) t^2\|u\|^2+2C^2 t\Re \langle u,v\rangle+C^2 \|v^2\|\\
\Leftrightarrow \forall u\in U, v\in V\colon\,C^4 \Re \langle u,v\rangle^2\leqslant C^2(C^2-1) \|v^2\|\cdot \|u\|^2,
$$
here $U$ and $V$ come in symmetric fashion, so $\|P\|\leqslant C$ if and only if $\|I-P\|\leqslant C$.