# How to prove $\|I-P\| = \|P\|$ for any non-trivial projector?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

I noticed that in the paper [1] this property is proved by explicitly computing the singular values of $P$ after realizing $P$ in finite dimension as oblique projection matrix. I am wondering if there is a simpler proof, or more abstract proof, for this property. Thanks!

Reference:
[1] Brust, J. J., Marcia, R. F., & Petra, C. G. (2020). Computationally efficient decompositions of oblique projection matrices. SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications, 41(2), 852-870.

Comment: See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409447/2-norm-of-idempotent-matrix/409621#409621

Comment: So $P:X\to X$ is a linear projector, not necessarily orthogonal, in a Hilbert space $X$? (for linear projector on a  normed space  I think in general $\|P\|\neq\|I-P\|$)